# ubuntu and unix stuff about directories and hidden files

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

In no way do i think i'm an adequate unix administrator but i'm learning. I `"cd"` into a specific directory and it appears to be empty after i do a "ls". But when i `"ll"` it says this:

```
/integration/import$ ll
```

total 184

What is this total 184? And how do i see these text files. I've never seen anything like this before. super confusing.

My co-worker had originally said this: in the imports folder find the text file containing this order and move it out of the folder/queue.

Comment: Looks like `ll` is an alias for `ls -l` on your system.  `total 184` is the total number of disk blocks taken by the files.  `man ls` is your friend.

Comment: try `ls -la .*` . This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Ahhh.. thank you... i never knew about man ls either. i'm looking at it now... can you elaborate what disk blocks taken by the files mean?

Comment: I agree that this question isn't necessarily *programming* in the way we define it here, but I think [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be a better fit than superuser.

Answer (score 0):

The below should list the hidden  files as well. Usually, hidden files are the one starting with a dot. e.g. `.mail` or so.

```
ls -latr  /integration/import/
```